# In User.register function in mongoose when i run it it gives me output of this

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

[image]

You can see my code:

[image]

I printed the req.body.password it is normal and using typeof() it is a string.

I was expecting no erros and the credentials to be stored in the db.

Comment: Why exactly do you wrap your password from body in an array? Please note that you should not post code as an image, but instead copy and paste the code (formatted).

Comment: I think it's the array as well. In JavaScript Arrays have a `typeof` `Object`